# lsblk doesn't show attached virtual storage / partition

Tags: centos, storage, lsblk

I attached a used virtual storage (backup) to a rescue instance because I need the files of the attached storage.

```
[root@centos-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 ~]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda    253:0    0   25G  0 disk
└─vda1 253:1    0   25G  0 part /
vdb    253:16   0  100G  0 disk
```

Any help how I get the files?

```
[root@centos-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 ~]# blkid
/dev/vda1: UUID="e8b504d0-0535-4585-b344-004c7111a5b1" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="97acc670-01"
/dev/vdb: UUID="d49fa7aa-e2f7-4959-b0d2-ba6ca77b645d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shown above, your vdb disk is not partitioned, but is formatted as a whole with a "ext4" filesystem. (Not that it makes a difference).  So, just make a mountpoint for it somewhere, and mount it (preferrably read-only?). Like...

```
mkdir /tmp/vdb
mount -r /dev/vdb /tmp/vdb
cd /tmp/vdb
ls -la
```

...and you should see the files.

Comment: Great @Pourko 
Thank you very much...it worked :-)